# Is it still possible to get the house in Windhelm if you end the civil war via the main story line rather than partaking in the war itself?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know during the main quest line you can end the war and create an alliance, but I also know that the only way I personally was able to purchase Hjerim is to participate in the Civil War questline. I would rather not do this for role playing purposes, but I still want to buy the home. Before I proceed with the main quest, I would like to know if this is possible.
Bear in mind that I'm on PS4, so I can't use console commands. Thank you in advance!

Note: I've already completed the quest *Blood on the Ice*, and have helped enough people to become Thane if possible after the alliance is formed. I just need to know if buying Hjerim is possible since I can't find mention of it as an option.

Answer (score 2):

The "end the war and create an alliance" you are referring to is neither of those things. It is a temporary ceasefire so the Dovahkiin can deal with the bigger, world-ending threat. After that threat is dealt with, both sides go back to fighting.

This does not lock you out of the Civil War quests, nor does it allow you to purchase Hjerim. You need to do one of the following:

- Join the Stormcloaks
- Complete the Civil War on the Imperial side, up to and including the siege of Windhelm

Answer (score 1):

Both [UESP.net](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim) and [elderscrolls.fandom.com](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Hjerim) note joining either side in the Civil War is necessary to be able to purchase Hjerim.

- Siding with the Imperial Legion, you must have defeated the Stormcloaks (that is [finished the Battle for Windhelm](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Windhelm));
- Having joined the Stormcloaks, the prerequisite slightly differs from the one site to the other, however. Respectively:

  > Once allied with the Stormcloaks, **the *'[Battle For Fort
  >   Sungard](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Sungard_(Stormcloaks))'* quest must be completed** before Jorleif will make the house
  >   available for sale.
  >   However, if Falkreath Hold has been given to the
  >   Stormcloaks as part of '*[Season Unending](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending)*', it may be necessary to
  >   liberate Hjaalmarch before Jorleif will make this house available.

  And

  > **Completing '[*Rescue from Fort Neugrad*](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Rescue_from_Fort_Neugrad)'** (for the Stormcloaks).

I'm not sure whether or not finishing '*Blood on the Ice*' without having joined either camp is sufficient qualification for letting a player buy the house, but **another possible reason Hjerim is unpurchasable is because the player is not a Thane of Windhelm.**

---

Among the [bugs](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hjerim#Bugs) on UESP you'll find that:

> The option to buy the house may exist, but you are unable to actually
>   purchase it even after completing the prerequisites, as the dialogue
>   still says it is unable to be purchased due to unpleasantness.

No solution is given there.

Comment: Why the downvote?